# How to remove Navigation button from login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement where my navigation button in right corner when viewed from the mobile view should be removed from the login page. As there is nothing to be displayed when button is clicked in the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about hidden-xs in button itself:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
```

It will hide the menu toggle button in small screens.

**EDIT:**
To apply it on the login page (if you can't use it directly) only use below jquery in the login page:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').addClass('hidden-xs');
```

Comment: I want to hide it only in my login page, i.e my first page. But if I give class="navbar-toggle hidden-xs" it will hide in all the pages which I dont want.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana Add this class to button using javascript on login page only.

Comment: where exactly should I add this in my javascript?

Comment: @ Jitesh Yadav the same problem. It is working for all the pages and not only for login page.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana That's because you are putting it in common js file which is being used by other pages as well. Just put it in the login page  itself. It should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100362/discussion-between-shruthi-sathyanarayana-and-jitesh-yadav).

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana there must be some login page scope right ? set a flag addClass there and use that in ng-class="addClass ? 'hidden-xs' : ''" in toggle button. Since this variable is set only in login scope.. the class will be added only for login page.

Comment: I have edited my question with my logincontroller.js. Where should I exactly modify the code

Answer (score 1):

You just add the css code with mobile view responsive css and add the properties to display:none for menu like as below :

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.menunameClass{
display:none;
}
}
```

May be it will resolve your problem.

Comment: It will happen in all pages and I dont want that. I want it to work only on my login page.

Comment: Ok! Just add the new class to your login page which is different to all other pages and put the css like this:@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.yourloginpageClassName .menunameClass{
display:none;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if($(window).width() <= 480 && window.location.href == 'your.login.pageurl'){
$(".navBtn").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: @Enes please accompany code with explanation in the answers. Especially when it doesn't work...